# SoundPlayer PlaySync() sleep(or delay) program C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Iam using Visual Studio 2012 to build a Queue-System program, and I use System.Media.SoundPlayer to play sound. Here is my shape of code:

```
public static SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
private void callNumber()
{
   update_number_to_database();
   player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("C:\1.wav");
   player.PlaySync();
   player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("C:\2.wav");
   player.PlaySync();
}
```

So, when someone press a button, it will call function callNumber(). In this function it will update something in database and play some sounds in order. For example:

The number | 1 | 2 | 3 | go to room | 1

I like to use SoundPlayer because it is so great: with PlaySync I don't need to care the order of sounds. It always wait to finish the previous sound, and put the next sound in queue.

However, my problem is, the function callNumber have to wait to finish sounds before recall it. But what I want is: When I press button, it should run function callNumber immediatly, and the sounds will be in queue.

Iam trying to use WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer as another way, but not easy as SoundPlayer, I will need to put all file in a playlist and play them. But what about if I press button 2 times fastly?

So sorry for my bad English but it is still hard for me to describe my problem.

Comment: _"But what about if I press button 2 times fastly?"_ -- what if you do? What _do_ you want to happen? There are a number of options for playing sounds in .NET, but regardless of which one you use, you need to decide what is supposed to happen if `callNumber()` is called again before the previously-started sounds are done playing. It's not clear from your question what you would want there. You could play the sounds from a different thread than is used to call `callNumber()`, but how to do that will depend on what exactly you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

**As much as i understand from your description :**

You can use yourPlayer.stop() or something like that to stop sounds first before replaying some sound else.

You can do this by create other function that stop players and then recall your callNumber() function.

Comment: what actually you want to do ?
i can't understand what you want !